# Refactoring Haskell code

Tags: haskell, refactoring, dry, typeclass

Can instantiating a typeclass be generalized?

I have following bits of Haskell code:

```
data Variable = Var Char (Maybe Integer)
    deriving (Eq)
instance Show Variable where
    show (Var c Nothing) = [c]
    show (Var c (Just n)) = c : show n

data Funcsymb = FuncS Char (Maybe Integer)
    deriving (Eq)
instance Show Funcsymb where
    show (FuncS c Nothing) = [c]
    show (FuncS c (Just n)) = c : show n

data Relsymb = RelS Char (Maybe Integer)
    deriving (Eq)
instance Show Relsymb where
    show (RelS c Nothing) = [c]
    show (RelS c (Just n)) = c : show n
```

Can I write it without so much duplication? I know I can just use `(Char, Maybe Integer)` for all three, but I'd rather have separate types.

Comment: If you like separate types, why don't you use `newtype`?

Comment: You could define "showSym :: Char -> Maybe Integer -> String". Also, you might want to make it clear which type it is in the text output.

Comment: @Zeta I'm not sure how `newtype` would help here. I'd still have to write three separate `instance`s, right?

Comment: @Veky yes but those would be rather trivial like `show (MyWrapper a) = show a` (of course you could do the same here) - if you don't need to overwrite anything other a simple type-synonym might be ok too

Comment: Hmm... so I define another (base) type, write show for it, and then define these three using it? Or are you saying that I can just say `instance Show (Char, Maybe Integer) where ...` without defining new type?

Comment: At the very least you could factor out `showWithPrefix :: (Show a) => Char -> Maybe a -> String` as `showWithPrefix c n = c : maybe "" show n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use make a helper function or two to reduce the repetition.

```
showIfJust :: (Show a) => Maybe a -> String
showIfJust (Just a) = show a
showIfJust _ = ""

showCharMaybe = (Show a) => Char -> Maybe a -> String
showCharMaybe c m = c : showIfJust m

data Variable = Var Char (Maybe Integer)
    deriving (Eq)

instance Show Variable where
    -- this can be written as
    -- c : showIfJust n
    -- or showCharMaybe c m
    show (Var c mn) = showCharMaybe c mn

data Funcsymb = FuncS Char (Maybe Integer)
    deriving (Eq)

instance Show Funcsymb where
    show (FuncS c mn) = showCharMaybe c mn

data Relsymb = RelS Char (Maybe Integer)
    deriving (Eq)

instance Show Relsymb where
    show (RelS c mn) = showCharMaybe c mn
```

Also, you can switch the `data` declarations to `newtype` since they are all single constructor declarations. It is a small optimization. [More details about newtype](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype).